# Phaser 3 3.55.2 pixelated graphics in mobile

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a game but I have updated from 3.15.1 to 3.55.2.

I solved all the problems but I see that the parameter "resolution" has been removed and now from mobile the graphic is pixelated.

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Please provide more details: Version of what ? What's wrong ? Screenshot ? Eventual relevant piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

Official statement about it - https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/CHANGELOG-v3.50.md#removal-of-resolution-property-from-across-the-api
So, it cant be fixed, because it never works.

But, maybe https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.1/focus/Phaser.Core.Config-pixelArt is enabled in your game, try to turn it off.